# How Gradle Plugin add method to a specific block?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I wonder how Gradle achieve this mechanism : add a specific method to a script block that only work in that block.

For example, If I want to use `implementation` method, I have to `apply plugin: 'java'`, But I can only use `implementation` in `dependencies{}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dependencies` block is just a [`DependencyHandler`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.java).
The default implementation is [`DefaultDependencyHandler`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/dependency-management/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/dsl/dependencies/DefaultDependencyHandler.java).
Note, that it implements [`MethodMixIn`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/metaobject/MethodMixIn.java):

> A decorated domain object type may optionally implement this interface to dynamically expose methods in addition to those declared statically on the type.
>   Note that when a type implements this interface, dynamic Groovy dispatch will not be used to discover opaque methods.
>   That is, methods such as `methodMissing()` will be ignored.

So, this mixin is something like a [`methodMissing`](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html) in Groovy.
Whenever an unknown method is called on a Groovy object, if it has `methodMissing` method, it is called.
`MethodMixIn` seem to work similarly.
It defines a single method:

```
MethodAccess getAdditionalMethods();
```

Let's look how it is implemented in `DefaultDependencyHandler`?

```
public MethodAccess getAdditionalMethods() {
    return dynamicMethods;
}
```

Where `dynamicMethods` is initialized as:

```
dynamicMethods = new DynamicAddDependencyMethods(configurationContainer, new DirectDependencyAdder());
```

Let's check the [`DynamicAddDependencyMethods`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/dependency-management/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/dsl/dependencies/DynamicAddDependencyMethods.java).
First, it defines a `hasMethod`, that returns `true` when there is a configuration with the given name:

```
public boolean hasMethod(String name, Object... arguments) {
    return arguments.length != 0 && configurationContainer.findByName(name) != null;
}
```

After applying Java plugin, you `configurations` will have objects like `api`, `implementation` and [so on](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations).
So, `hasMethod("api")` will return `true`, while `hasMethod("API")` – `false`, unless you have another plugin that contributes a configuration with that name.

Finaly, `tryInvokeMethod` in invoked whenever a configuration name is used like a function in `dependencies` block:

```
public DynamicInvokeResult tryInvokeMethod(String name, Object... arguments) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) {
        return DynamicInvokeResult.notFound();
    }
    Configuration configuration = configurationContainer.findByName(name);
    if (configuration == null) {
        return DynamicInvokeResult.notFound();
    }

    List<?> normalizedArgs = CollectionUtils.flattenCollections(arguments);
    if (normalizedArgs.size() == 2 && normalizedArgs.get(1) instanceof Closure) {
        return DynamicInvokeResult.found(dependencyAdder.add(configuration, normalizedArgs.get(0), (Closure) normalizedArgs.get(1)));
    } else if (normalizedArgs.size() == 1) {
        return DynamicInvokeResult.found(dependencyAdder.add(configuration, normalizedArgs.get(0), null));
    } else {
        for (Object arg : normalizedArgs) {
            dependencyAdder.add(configuration, arg, null);
        }
        return DynamicInvokeResult.found();
    }
}
```

As you see, it just looks up for a named configuration and adds the dependency to it.

That's how it's made.

Comment: This question has puzzled me for months, hugely thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ratsafalig - Just a suggestion: If an answer is helpful, you can vote for it. But if you are the one who asked the question, you should also consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), by clicking on the check mark. This step is completely optional - but [very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: This desperately needs to be in the Gradle docs for DependencyHandler.  Thank you for this!