# gradle: mysterious DSL, why does nested dependency declaration works but not documented?

Tags: gradle, dsl

for example (Gradle 7.1):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation('com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:5.19') {
        // TODO: just for producing same fat jar as before, should be removed so can get newer version
        implementation('com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:4.29') {
            force true
        }
        implementation('com.nimbusds:lang-tag:1.4.3') {
            force true
        }
    }
}
```

See the nested `implementation` declaration? I just imagined and wrote that, it worked as imagined, but I could not find document about it.

Given a keyword, such as `dependencies`, I can easily find what it is by holding Cmd or Ctl key and click the keyword in IntelliJ IDEA, it shows

```
void dependencies(Closure var1);
```

The problem is that no further help for what can I write in the Closure, I know the Closure is like a callback function block, from the document, I can know some limited usage of it, but not the full!

I can also click the keyword such as `exclude` in the `implementation` block, to find its sibling methods, but obviously, it is not the full method list.

```
public interface ModuleDependency extends Dependency, HasConfigurableAttributes<ModuleDependency> {
    ModuleDependency exclude(Map<String, String> var1);

    Set<ExcludeRule> getExcludeRules();

    Set<DependencyArtifact> getArtifacts();

    ModuleDependency addArtifact(DependencyArtifact var1);

    DependencyArtifact artifact(@DelegatesTo(value = DependencyArtifact.class,strategy = 1) Closure var1);

    DependencyArtifact artifact(Action<? super DependencyArtifact> var1);

    boolean isTransitive();

    ModuleDependency setTransitive(boolean var1);

    @Nullable
    String getTargetConfiguration();

    void setTargetConfiguration(@Nullable String var1);

    ModuleDependency copy();

    AttributeContainer getAttributes();

    ModuleDependency attributes(Action<? super AttributeContainer> var1);

    ModuleDependency capabilities(Action<? super ModuleDependencyCapabilitiesHandler> var1);

    List<Capability> getRequestedCapabilities();

    void endorseStrictVersions();

    void doNotEndorseStrictVersions();

    boolean isEndorsingStrictVersions();
}
```

And if I check the `force` keyword in the `implementation` block, it points me to another place, so on and on.

```
public interface ExternalDependency extends ModuleDependency, ModuleVersionSelector {
    boolean isForce();

    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    ExternalDependency setForce(boolean var1);

    ExternalDependency copy();

    void version(Action<? super MutableVersionConstraint> var1);

    VersionConstraint getVersionConstraint();
}
```

So far the best document I found is https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html, but still it is just some examples, not the full list.

**Can anyone tell me where is the full document?**

PS: thank p.streef for pointing out the most complete reference page is https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html, but it is still not clear. I reallized that my question is actually about how does the gradle DSL works, e.g., there is no java method named `implementation` there, but gradle can use it, it must be some kind of syntax sugar, I'd like to know which java method it calls and with what parameters?, I suspect it calls

```
add(configurationName, dependencyNotation, configureClosure)
```

so I can further add dependencyNotation in the configureClosure, thus nested `implementation` works.

but I have no proof.

Comment: is this what you are looking for: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html?

Comment: thank you! Probably this page is the best one. But still can not find why I can nest `implementation` keyword without error, maybe it is just because groovy call parentObject.implementation.

Comment: Besides, can anyone tell me how does gradle `implementation` keyword works? it is seems like a groovy sugar, there is no such method actually.

Comment: It's a method tied to the implementation configuration. That is probably why it's not listed. Why you can nest it I'm not sure, I doubt it does anything useful though.

Comment: I updated my question, see the PS section.

Comment: @p.streef thank you. It works as expected, I have confirmed the result of with and without it, results are different, without it, the final fat jar use the newer version. I have not test the result of moving the nested definitions to first level, but the important thing is that why nest `implementation` declaration works and not documented?

Comment: Found a useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321825/2293666

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

https://dzone.com/articles/groovy-closures-owner-delegate helps a lot.

> there is no java method named implementation there, but gradle can use it, it must be some kind of syntax sugar, I'd like to know which java method it calls and with what parameters?

The groovy has a `methodMissing` method,

```
class ... {
  //
  // ...
  // In every Groovy object methodMissing() is invoked when a method that does not exist on the object is invoked
  // In this case, there is no name() method so methodMissing will be invoked. 
  // ...
  def methodMissing(String methodName, args) {
...
```

probably gradle use it to call

```
add(configurationName, dependencyNotation, configureClosure)
```

> why nested `implementation` declaration works?

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation('com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:5.19') {
        println resolveStrategy == Closure.OWNER_ONLY ////////see here
        implementation('com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:4.29') {
            force true
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested that the Closure of the `implementation` use
`resolveStrategy` `Closure.OWNER_ONLY`, which means the the outer instance, i.e., the `dependencies` instance.

So the `methodMissing` method of the `dependencies` instance will be invoked.

Also, there is another similar useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321825/2293666